# How can I find the actual location of the SAS metadata folders?

Tags: sas

In SAS Management Console, there's this whole virtual directory of folders. Where can I actually find them on the server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They do not exist on the server in the same sense as a file directory structure. They are stored in metadata repositories on the metadata server. The metadata repository is not stored in a format that you can browse through on your filesystem. You can, however, access it through a variety of tools, such as SAS Management Console, PROC METADATA, and the XML-based [Open Metadata Interface API](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=omaref&docsetTarget=titlepage.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en).

If you are curious at what it physically looks like, you can find it in the default repository at `Your-SAS-Config-Directory-Here/Lev1/SASMeta/MetadataServer/MetadataRepositories`.

Comment: So if I wanted to take one of the files from this virtual directory, say `<virtual directory root>/User Folders/<username>/My Folder`, how would I get that file?

Comment: In SAS Management Console, right-click the file and select "Write Content to External File"

Answer (score 2):

As Stu says, the folders are just logical folders.  The same concept applies in SAS Viya.

Fyi, if you want to export your SAS 9 folder tree to a dataset, you can use the [@sasjs/core](https://github.com/sasjs/core) library -

```
* load macros;
filename mc url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sasjs/core/main/all.sas";
%inc mc;

* export everything;
%mm_tree(outds=iwantthisdataset)
```

Documentation is [here](https://core.sasjs.io/mm__tree_8sas_source.html).